# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while fetching a cgi file

Tags: javascript, python, json, fetch, cgi

I'm getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input \

Javascript:

```
fetch("cgi-bin/test.cgi")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

test.cgi:

```
import json
import cgi

testval = "ok"
b= {"testkey": testval}


print("Content-Type: application/json")
print()
print(json.dumps(b))
```

Any idea what i could do about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The response value is empty. What kind of a cgi file converts to JSON anyway?

Comment: Have you tried fetching using CURL and is the output correct?